# XAxis labels not shown despite stringForValue getting called

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have a LineChartView and I want to show labels for the xAxis. 
My code looks like this:

```
    chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    chartView.dragEnabled = !chartView.isFullyZoomedOut
    chartView.setScaleEnabled(true)
    chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = true
    chartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 20.0, top: 0.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 0.0)

    chartView.legend.enabled = true
    chartView.legend.textColor = legendColor
    chartView.legend.form = .empty

    chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.4
    chartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.4
    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

    chartView.xAxis.enabled = true
    chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.black
    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

    chartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
    chartView.highlightPerDragEnabled = false

    if lineChartData.entryCount > 0 {
        chartView.data = lineChartData
    }
    chartView.noDataText = NSLocalizedString("No chart data available", comment: String())
    chartView.maxVisibleCount = 12
    chartView.delegate = self
```

and

```
extension ChartCell: IAxisValueFormatter {
   func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
       return "foo"
   }
```

}

In the debugger I see that stringForValue is being called, however in the drawn charts there are no labels. 
[image: line chart without xAxis labels]
I'm at a loss what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set below :

```
chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
```

Comment: Almost, I needed to use XAxis.LabelPosition.bottomInside for it to work. Thanks! I think maybe my setup with having the lineChartView inside a UITableViewCell causes only label positions with *inside to work